# Como fazer um Carousel?

Tags: java, android, carousel

Estou tentando criar um Carousel no Android como o [deste video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p_WIvH3Xo4c) ([código fonte](https://github.com/captswag/carousel-viewpager)) mas não está dando muito certo.

Comment: É melhor você detalhar mais seu problema aqui pois talvez ninguém vá tirar um tempo para assistir seu vídeo. Melhore suas perguntas para ter mais sucesso nas suas respostas.

Comment: Desculpe, o meu problema e o seguinte, preciso criar um carousel para exibir cards como se fosse imagens tipo um slide show

Comment: Então cara, se você não dizer o que está dando errado, ninguém vai poder te ajudar. Você não pode simplesmente falar que está errado sem mostra o erro.

Comment: Melhor dizendo, eu preciso de ajuda para fazer. Os exemplos q eu achei estão muito confusos, é isso.

Comment: Você quer que alguém faça para você ou quer ajuda para resolver o que você tentou fazer? Teria como você pelo menos postar alguma foto, código, ou algo parecido. Eu estou no meu job, nem posso abrir seu vídeo.

Comment: Não é fazer para mim, eu queria um exemplo e uma explicação da criação, como eu falei, os exemplos que eu vi estou achando complicado de mais, não estou conseguindo entender o desenvolvimento. Eu apaguei o que eu estava tentando fazer, por isso não coloquei. Na próxima eu deixou o codigo.

Comment: @carlosgiovanicasilo Você disse que não está dando muito certo. Para podermos te ajudar melhor, você poderia dizer o que não está dando certo? Se possível editar sua pergunta com o seu problema, efetivamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vamos lá! Primeiramente você precisa criar um elemento `ViewPager` dentro de sua `xml` desta forma `res/layout/activity_main.xml`:

#### XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Para customizar seu adapter, você precisa criar `res/layout/pager_item.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

</LinearLayout>
```

#### Adapter

Depois disso, você pode criar o `adapter` customizado para definir o seu `ViewPager`:

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private int[] mResources;

    public CustomPagerAdapter(Context context, int[] resources) {
        mContext = context;
        mResources = resources;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pager_item, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

        container.addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }

}
```

#### Activity

Em seguida, coloque o seguinte código no `onCreate` na sua `Activity`:

```
mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

// Aqui estao suas imagens dentro do drawable
int[] mResources = {
    R.drawable.first,
    R.drawable.second,
    R.drawable.third,
    R.drawable.fourth,
    R.drawable.fifth,
    R.drawable.sixth
};

CustomPagerAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this, mResources);

mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
```

Veja [este tutorial](http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/) para mais detalhes.

#### CardView

Para você fazer uma adaptação usando cardview, você precisa alterar seu `res/layout/pager_item.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- A CardView that contains a TextView -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

O widget [CardView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html?hl=pt-br) é parte da [Biblioteca de Suporte v7](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html?hl=pt-br#v7). Para usar esse widget no projeto, adicione esta dependência do Gradle ao módulo do aplicativo:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:21.0.+'
}
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado pela ajuda. Vou testar agora. Valeu mesmo.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, mais uma vez obrigado. Agora, me surgiu uma duvida, nesse exemplo esta sendo utilizado 6 imagens, ao chegar na ultima teria como fazer com que ele continue voltando para a primeira?

Comment: @carlosgiovanicasilo você poderia marcar essa questão como válida e fazer outra pergunta no Stackoverflow. É melhor que melhora sua pontuação, minha pontuação, e outras pessoas podem também te ajudar na resposta. =)