# Loop em Carousel

Tags: java, android, carousel

Estou fazendo um `Carousel`, que recebi a [ajuda de amigo daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/148428/como-fazer-um-carousel). Mas agora surgiu um pequeno problema, no exemplo existem 6 imagens, e ao chegar na última ele para. Queria saber como eu faço para que ao chegar na última, ele volte para a primeira, tipo um loop.

Comment: Fala @Carlos giovani casilo, naum testei mas acredito que, supondo que vc sabe o numero de imagens que tem na lista da sua matriz, se fizer algo tipo isso nesta linha `imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position==nrLista?0:position]);` funcionaria para voce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tive uma ideia de fazer desta forma, porém existe outras maneiras de fazer.

## Main

```
public class MainViewPage extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager mViewPager;

    int[] mResources = {
            R.mipmap.imagem1,
            R.mipmap.imagem2,
            R.mipmap.imagem3,
            R.mipmap.imagem4,
            R.mipmap.imagem5,
            R.mipmap.imagem6
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.carousel);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        CarouselAdapter mCustomPagerAdapter = new CarouselAdapter(this, mResources);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);


    }
}
```

## Adapter

```
public class CarouselAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private Context mContext;
    private LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    private int[] mResources;


    private int pos = 0;

    public CarouselAdapter(Context context, int[] resources) {
        mContext = context;
        mResources = resources;
        mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_carousel, container, false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        imageView.setImageResource(mResources[pos]);

        container.addView(itemView);

        if (pos >= mResources.length - 1)
            pos = 0;
        else
            ++pos;

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
    }

}
```

## XML

Neste caso do XML, já está adaptado com o `CardView`

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|center_horizontal"
        card_view:cardElevation="8dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

## Screenshots

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dê uma olhada neste projeto [InfiniteViewPager](https://github.com/angelorohit/InfiniteViewPager), que também tem ajudará a ter mais alguma ideia de como fazer. Abaixo segue um exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito obrigado, vou testar agora mesmo.

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado mesmo.

Comment: @carlosgiovanicasilo existe outras variações de como resolver isso. Depois de mais uma pesquisada para melhoria. Abs